# How to make OpenGL apps in 64-bit Windows?

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, visual-studio-2005, 64-bit

My project compiles, link and run in xp32 then I tried to cross compile it to x64 and I came across a lot of questions:

1. There's no native x64 instalable OpenGL SDK so I link against what?
2. I saw someone saying that x64 apps use 32bits opengl dll. I tryied to run my compiled 64-bits app in a xp64 with drivers to my video card (radeon 4850), the same I use on xp32 and I got that typical error "bla bla bla, maybe reinstalling you application will resolve the problem"
3. If I use video card drivers how to keep it working with another Cards, should I build a version for each? (no sense). Should I load an available library dinamicaly? (same no sense)
4. Which is the reference implementation for x64? where do I find its libs to link against?

I'm really lost on that matter. I did a lot of searchs and found nothing that helped me understant till the momment.

So, what is the path? What I want to know to make native x64 OpenGL apps?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The 64-bit OpenGL import library is included in the [Windows SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bb980924.aspx) and gets installed to `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\<version>\Lib\x64\OpenGL32.lib`. The corresponding DLL is named `opengl32.dll` and is located in `%SystemRoot%\system32`. The 32-bit version is also named `opengl32.dll` and is located in `%SystemRoot%\syswow64` on 64-bit Windows.

You can't load 32-bit DLLs in a 64-bit process, so whatever you read about x64 apps using the 32-bit OpenGL DLL was incorrect. There is definitely a 64-bit OpenGL DLL, but it has "32" in its name, presumably to make porting easier.

Comment: Oh, I did not know it. That is wierd.

Comment: I'm not sure that is Microsofts fault: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL and https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/164499-Who-maintains-OpenGL

Answer (score 1):

The OpenGL static and dynamic libraries `OpenGL32.lib` and `opengl32.dll` for 32-bit or 64-bit applications come with the OS and are now respectively in the Windows directories listed below. Just keep in mind that the 32-bit and the 64-bit OpenGL (and glew) libraries are named the same for historical reasons.

If you are using Visual Studio in Windows, no need to copy the `opengl32.dll` library in your `Debug` or `Release` directories where is your `.exe` or the path to `OpenGL32.lib` in Visual Studio - only add "Opengl32.lib" in `Properties`, `Linker`, `Input`, then `Additional Dependencies`.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x86
C:\Windows\System32

C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.14393.0\um\x64
C:\Windows\SysWOW64
```