# Where is opengl32.lib located?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I was trying to compile my OpenGL program using this command

```
g++ triangleOpenagl/tutorialLevel/src/main.cpp triangleOpenagl/tutorialLevel/src/glad.c -I Dependencies/Includes/GLAD/include -I Dependencies/Includes/GLFW/include Dependencies/Libs/GLFW/lib-vc2019/glfw3.lib
```

now I need to add opengl32.lib but I don't know where it is. can anyone tell me the exact location on windows 10 LTS?

P.S. i did some research and it's not inside Microsoft SDKs

Comment: "P.S. i did some research and it's not inside Microsoft SDKs" How come? It should be inside `%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\\Lib\x64`

Comment: I remember that the `opengl32.lib` is the already deprecated OpenGL 1.1 implementation by Microsoft. In order to access up-to-date, hardware accelerated OpenGL implementation you'd need something like GLAD. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986459/where-to-get-an-up-to-date-opengl32-lib. Also if a tutorial tells you to link to `opengl32.lib`, maybe it's very aged already, and you might want to switch to a modern one.

Answer (score 2):

Using [everything](https://www.voidtools.com/), I was able to find the location of all opengl32.lib locations on all my hard drives in like 3 seconds. I recommend you use it to find your own.

[image: opengl32.lib locations]

Answer (score 0):

I found OpenGL32.Lib in the following directory (Windows 10): 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Lib\x64`

If you are looking for the .dll, I found opengl32.dll in the following directory: 
`C:\Windows\System32\`

[This](https://jan.ucc.nau.edu/jdp85/classes/CS499F06/installingOpenGL.html) is a good reference for installing OpenGL, GLUT and/or Fltk on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

File location (depending on your installation and OS):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64> opengl32.lib

How to find `opengl32.lib` file:

Open Powershell:

```
cd c:
Get-ChildItem opengl32.lib -Recurse
```

or

```
Get-ChildItem opengl32.lib -Path C: -Recurse
```