# C# opengl context handle getter returns wrong address

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, interop, opencl

Problem solved!

- Deleted pragma of sharing from kernel string.(using opencl 1.2)
- Reordered GL-VBO-creating and CL-Context-Creating. First create CL-context from gl-context. Then create GL-VBO. Then acquire it by cl. Then compute. Then release by cl. Then bind by gl. Draw. Finish gl. Start over. Use clFinish always to ensure it synchs with gl. For more speed, clflush can be okay maybe even an implicit sync can be done which I did not try.

[image: okey]

[original question from here]

In C#, context construction for opencl-gl-interop fails because handle getter function gives wrong address and causes `System.AccessViolationException`.

C# part:

```
[DllImport("opengl32.dll",EntryPoint="wglGetCurrentDC")]
extern static IntPtr wglGetCurrentDC();//CAl

[DllImport("opengl32.dll", EntryPoint = "wglGetCurrentContext")]
extern static IntPtr wglGetCurrentContext();// DCAl
```

C++ part in opencl(this is in a wrapper class of C++ opencl):

```
pl = new cl_platform_id[2];
clGetPlatformIDs( 1, pl, NULL);
cl_context_properties props[] ={ CL_GL_CONTEXT_KHR, (cl_context_properties)CAl,
CL_WGL_HDC_KHR, (cl_context_properties)DCAl,CL_CONTEXT_PLATFORM, 
(cl_context_properties)&pl[0],  0};

ctx=cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU,props,NULL,NULL,NULL);//error comes from here
//ctx=cl::Context(CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU); this does not interop  >:c
```

What is wrong in these parts? When I change "opengl32.dll" to "opengl64.dll" compiler/linker cannot find it.

Calling `wglGetCurrentDC()` and `wglGetCurrentContext()` after `glControl1` is loaded but these seem to be giving wrong addresses. Calling `wglMakeCurrent()` or `glControl1.MakeCurrent()` before those did not solve the problem too.

OS: 64 bit windows7

Host: fx8150

Device: HD7870

MSVC2012(windows forms application) + OpenTK(2010_10_6) + Khronos opencl 1.2 headers

Build target is x64(release).

Note: opencl part is working well for computing(sgemm) and opengl part is drawing VBO well (some  plane built of triangles with some color and normals) but opencl part(context) refuses to interop.

**Edit:** Adding `#pragma OPENCL EXTENSION cl_khr_gl_sharing : enable` into kernel string did not solve the problem.

**Edit:** Creating GL VBOs "after" the construction of cl context, error vanishes but nothing is updated by opencl kernel. Weird. PLus, when I delete cl_khr_sharing pragma, the 3D shape starts artifacting which means opencl is doing something now but its just random deleted pixels and some cropped areas which I did not wrote in kernel. Weirdier. You can see this in below picture(I am trying to make the flat blue sheet disappear but it doesnt fully disappear and also i try changing color and that is not changing)

[image: here]

**Edit:** CMSoft's opencltemplate looks like what I need to learn/do but their example code consists only 6-7 lines of code! I dont know where to put compute kernel and where to get/set initial data, but that example works great(gives hundreds of "WARNING! ComputeBuffer{T}(575296656) leaked." by the way).

**Edit:** In case you wonder, here is kernel arguments' construction in C++:

```
//v1,v2,v3,v4 are unsigned int taken from `bindbuffer` of GL in C#
//so v1 is buf[0] and v2 is buf[1] and so goes like this
glBuf1=cl::BufferGL(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,v1,0); 
glBuf2=cl::BufferGL(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,v2,0); 
glBuf3=cl::BufferGL(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,v3,0); 
glBuf4=cl::BufferGL(ctx,CL_MEM_READ_WRITE,v4,0);
```

and here is how set into command queue:

```
v.clear();
v.push_back(glBuf1);
v.push_back(glBuf2);
v.push_back(glBuf3);
v.push_back(glBuf4);

cq.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&v,0,0);
cq.finish();
```

and here is how I set as arguments of kernel:

```
kernel.setArg(0,glBuf1);
kernel.setArg(1,glBuf2);
kernel.setArg(2,glBuf3);
kernel.setArg(3,glBuf3);
```

here is how executed:

```
cq.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel,referans,Global,Local);
cq.flush();
cq.finish();
```

here is how released:

```
cq.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&v,0,0);
cq.finish();
```

Simulation iteration:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
{
     GL.Finish(); // lets cl take over

     //cl acquires buffers in glTest
     clh.glTest(gci.buf[0], gci.buf[1], gci.buf[2], gci.buf[3]);// then computes
     // then releases
     Thread.Sleep(50);
     glControl1.MakeCurrent();
     glControl1.Invalidate();
     gci.ciz(); //draw
}
```

Comment: **2 Questions:** Do you have the "opengl64.dll" in the working directory?  Is your wrapper class built using the x64 instruction set?

Comment: @Kirk Backus Yes its build using x64 instruction set. I cant find both opengl32.dll and 64 version Where are they usually?. I need x64 because Im using more than 5-6 GB ram and using AVX-intrinsics in C++ part.

Comment: Wow!  Well, you can search your computer for them!  They will typically reside in the `C:\Windows\System32` directory.  According to the link I posted, there is a 64 bit version with 32 in its name.

Comment: Found this for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236670/how-to-make-opengl-apps-in-64-bits-windows

Comment: Okay, sorted the problem out. Thank you for your efforts. Put the answer in the head of question.