# Compile OpenGL with GCC 64-bit

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, 64-bit, glew

I have a project that compiles with GCC 32-bit. I have been trying to migrate to GCC 64-bit on my native Windows machine (not through a VM). To do this I have downloaded w64devkit from https://github.com/skeeto/w64devkit/releases. My 32-bit install comes from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/.

NOTE: Both installs cannot be active at the same time. Since the 32-bit version makes it into the path before we can add the 64-bit version through the environment variables, I modify the 32-bit MinGW folder name so that when the 64-bit version of GCC tries to use as.exe and ld.exe through the path, it will find the correct versions.

I have also downloaded glm, glew, and glfw for this project, and added folders to the path to get at least the 32-bit version working.

The working command line to compile the 32-bit version is as follows:

`g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -ggdb src/main.cpp -o build/main -lopengl32 -L. -I"C:\lib\glm" -I"C:\lib\glew-2.1.0-win32\include" -I"C:\lib\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\include"  "C:\lib\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32\lib\libglfw3dll.a" "C:\lib\glew-2.1.0-win32\lib\Release\Win32\glew32.lib"`

The following command line to compile the 64-bit version also works:

`g++ -std=c++11 -O0 -ggdb src/main.cpp -o build/main -lopengl32 -L. -I"C:\lib\glm" -I"C:\lib\glew-2.1.0-win32\include" -I"C:\lib\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN64\include"  "C:\lib\glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN64\lib-mingw-w64\libglfw3dll.a" "C:\lib\glew-2.1.0-win32\lib\Release\x64\glew32.lib"`

However whenever I try to run the executables, the 32-bit version runs and the 64-bit version gives me an error in a pop-up window. "The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application."

When I try to run it in one of my debuggers I get a "Error: 32-bit processes are not supported". Another debugger says "During startup program exited with code 0xc000007b".

Clearly something is going horribly wrong, but I don't know what or where.

Comment: Did you try to specify the full path to gcc instead of relying on the shell to find it?
Something like C:\Program Files\...\g++.exe

Comment: @Mickaël C. Guimarães Yes, but I'm not sure what problem you think that will fix unless you're referring to my note. I found that problem because the assembler would print thousands of lines of errors.

Comment: I suspect you are calling the 32-bit version of g++ instead of 64-bit, as both are accessible from the PATH envvar

Comment: @Mickaël C. Guimarães I explain in my note that whenever I try to run the 64 bit compiler, I modify the MinGW folder so that programs searching on the path for it can no longer find it. I know this works because if I try to run the 64-bit compiler using the full path without modifying the folder, it will use the 32-bit assembler and crash. After modifying the folder, it will use the correct assembler and not crash

Comment: To be extra certain, I have done as you stated in your first comment, and the result is the same.

Comment: Ok, now I spotted some strange things in your command line calls : you are linking 32 bit libs in you 64 bit build.. If you want a 64 bit executable, you should link against 64 libs too.

Comment: @MickaëlC.Guimarães According to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1236670/how-to-make-opengl-apps-in-64-bit-windows OpenGL libraries are called the same thing. If you're not talking about the -lopengl32 option, the GLEW and GLFW are 64-bit in the 64-bit command line option. For GLFW the glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN32 becomes glfw-3.3.8.bin.WIN64 and for GLEW instead of Release/Win32 becomes Release/x64.